# How to achieve certificate pinning with Open ID appAuth?

Tags: ios, certificate, pinning, appauth

I'm using AppAuth for my iOS and android app. After android N, android has a way to add certificate pinning to all network requests while iOS has nothing like this.
Now I used TrustKit to achieve this in my API calls but how do I achieve certificate pinning with AppAuth?

Comment: Is there any answer or suggestion for this question?